# Should I replace those texts on buttons by meaningful icons?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, mobile-application, user-expectation

I own an application where users can organize meetings.
Other users can participate.

Here's a screen on the meeting I created: (so logged user is the creator)

[image]

We can notice the three buttons at the bottom, allowing respectively to:

- Edit the meeting: changing the title or description for instance
- Cancel his participation: for example if one user (including creator) desists.
- Delete the meeting: when the creator wants to delete it

Should I replace those texts on buttons by meaningful icons?
If yes, which icons would fit best? Especially for the "Cancel/Desist".

Comment: So a recipient which doesn't actively accept will automatically accept? Shouldn't you want it the other way around?

Comment: May you rephrase what you mean? I'm not sure to well interpret.

Comment: You say that there's a dedicated button for Canceling or Declining a meeting, but where's the button for accepting the meeting?

Comment: Oh ok :) Actually, those buttons are conditionally displayed: if the user hasn't participated yet, he can just see the button "Participate". Otherwise he can see "Cancel", cancelling his participation if he changed his mind. Bonus: if the logged user is the creator: he can additionally edit, or delete the meeting". A creator can cancel its own participation according to my use cases, that's why my OP show the three buttons at the same time.

Comment: Oh OK, then I understand

Comment: The tricky part is to find meaningful icons representing "Cancel" and "Participate". Or maybe should I keep text...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Preface:** We should all strive to make the UI as simple as possible.  What you have here will work for your users but there are ways to improve it based on who your users are.

**Icons or Words?**
If space provides you should use Icons *and* Text to communicate the action.  Icons should be left aligned in the button to have an equal indentation for the button label (edit/cancel/delete) and ease of reading/scanning.  The reasoning for icons and text is such that if you can teach the user what the icons mean then when you need to only show icons the user will still know what they do.  NOTE: This may have occurred earlier in the app in which case, icons alone might work in this instance.

Icon Suggestions:

- **Edit**: A pencil in a square or just a pencil normally implies "Edit" (would link but don't have enough reputation yet)
- [**Cancel**](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/times/) an "X" as in what you would do to close a window.
- [**Delete**](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/trash/) a "Trashcan" sometimes an "X" works for delete but normally "X" means "close" so in this case since the data is being removed, a trashcan works better.

In this example however it would make the most sense to have one button: 
"Edit".  "Cancel" could be an "X" in the right corner of the screen and/or a swipe from left to right implying that the user would get back to the screen that allowed them to get to this screen.  This "swipe" from left to right implies that this screen would be loaded or shown to the user animating in from right to left however (if you add a swipe make sure you animate this screen in the opposite direction). If the screen comes in from the bottom then you'd need to add a swipe from top to bottom to cancel it.  Make sense?

The "Delete" action should be moved into the "Edit" interface and should be colored "red".  In the example you've given, I can see quite a few of your users accidentally tapping cancel or delete while trying to reach for "Edit" which will frustrate them.  Especially since these buttons are destructive in nature rather than navigation elements as a tab row at the bottom of the screen would be recommended for.

Comment: "Cancel" could be an "X" in the right corner => I already use this zone for displaying a button leading to a chat between all meeting's participants.  IMHO, many users find "swiping" non-intuitive. Many lambda users don't even know what it is (my app targets public)

Comment: Have you done User Research?  I think that will tell you what your users are trying to do or not.  You might be surprised at what you observe. Especially given the most popular apps (Facebook, Mail, Safari, etc.) all use that action for "cancel".

Comment: Yes, you're right :)

Comment: "I can see quite a few of your users accidentally tapping cancel or delete while trying to reach for "Edit"" : A popup is prompts asking for confirmation. Would it make the trick? Or should I really put the delete functionality in the Edit screen.

Comment: It depends on your users ultimately, but when it doubt follow established paradigms used by other flows your customers use.

Most applications especially calendar/appointment applications have the "delete" command in the "edit" form.  That being said, a shortcut like swiping left in a list view would be beneficial or similar.  The goal is to give the user 1-2 tap actions. Other interactions could be communicated by other actions: swipe up/down/left/right, tap hold, etc.

Regarding a "confirmation" on delete.  That's also bad.  The best is to provide an "undo" after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

On an application, displaying a single text can be less user-friendly than displaying an icon that everyone can understand easily.

The issue can be the choice of your icons, between "Cancel" and "Delete", there's a thin subtlety.
So I suggest to display both text and icon (since one cannot 'alt' a image on an application) with relevant icons :

```
Edit + a pen icon
Cancel + a cross icon
Delete + a trash icon
```

[image]

Comment: As Jesse said in his post, the cross generally means "closing", not "cancelling".

Comment: This can be replaced by a "stop" icon. But the cross is also acceptable. See http://semantic-ui.com/elements/icon.html#/basic for example.